# SQL Server: populating a table based on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, subquery, correlated-subquery

I have two tables tblA (Pid int, Lid int, upcoming_Lid int)

```
(123, 10,null),
(345, 10,null),
(567, 11, null),
(457, 11,null)
```

tblB (Pid int, Lid int, isActive int)

```
(123,10,1),
(123,11,0),
(123,12,0),
(123,13,1),
(345,10,1),
(345,11,1),
(567,11,1),
(567,12,1),
(457,11,1),
(457,12,0),
(457,13,1)
```

Now, I want to populate tblA.upcoming_Lid from tblB where the next lid is active for the same Pid.
desired result from tblA:

```
(123, 10,13),
(345, 10,11),
(567, 11,12),
(457, 11,13)
```

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not show any attempts. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort. Update your question with what you've tried or what you've researched on your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf51b/1) demonstrates the following query:

```
UPDATE tblA
SET upcoming_Lid =
(
  SELECT Lid 
  FROM tblB
  WHERE tblA.Pid = tblB.Pid 
  AND tblB.isActive = 1
  AND tblB.Lid > tblA.Lid 
)
```

Comment: How would the code be different if I have Lid in tblB as varchar(2) so, for lid 10 I have A1, 11 I have Y5, 12 I habe B3. ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate functions to get that table populated.

Something like this:

```
create table new_table as
select Pid, min(Lid), max(Lid)
 where tblB.isActive = 1
  from tblB group by Pid;
```